# Why's my XPath String-length not working? (Java)

Tags: java, xpath

```
WebElement sendBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    "//*[contains(.,'About') and contains(.,'/') and (string-length(text()) < 9)]"
));
```

I am trying to get it to select an element that contains the word "about" the letter "/" and the string length of less than 9 but it's doesn't select the right elements.

Comment: Can you show an example of the strings that are treated wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

`contains()` applies to all text descendants, so if you don't specify the element name, you might get all ancestors of the nodes that actually contain the specified string.

To only apply the predicates to the actual texts in the elements, replace `.` with `text()`:

```
//*[ contains(text(), 'About')
     and contains(text(), '/')
     and string-length(text()) < 9
   ]
```